# How do I bypass metadata when checking for empty folder (Java)?

Tags: java, linux, file, directory-structure

I have simple directory list GUI that displays all the contents of a specified folder or file. I'm attempting to create a JOptionPane to alert a user that the folder is empty, however, an empty folder is still popping up on my JTable with 4 KB of data. I am on a Linux machine, so I am assuming this is the metadata.

This program was written using Swing, and I was required to simply add to two methods. Everything works, but I would really prefer to notify the user of an empty folder, since they most likely would not be concerned with the metadata. Here is what I tried (Note - I'm new to Swing since I'm accustomed to JavaFX):

```
    if(f.list().length == 0) {
      JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(emptyPanel, "That Directory is empty.", "OOPS!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Thanks for any help. By the way, "f" is the File object that was created in another method.

Comment: What files is `f.list()` returning when you expect it to be empty?  You can use a `FileFilter` to filter the results that `File#list`, see [`File#listFiles(FileFilter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles-java.io.FileFilter-) for more details. PS- This is pretty basic Java, nothing to do with Swing ;)

Comment: I should have specified that. For example, my Documents folder is empty, however, the folder pops up on the JTable with 4KB of data. I would like to bypass that and say it's empty.

Comment: Thanks for that info! I'll get right on looking into File Filter as soon as I'm back at my machine.

Answer (score 1):

If there is 1 metadata file in every folder, than the obvious solution would be to check if it was equal to one, not zero. If, however that metadata file is only sometimes there, then you could check if there was only 1 file in the list after you do the 0 check, and if there was, check if it is named as the metadata file is.

Comment: I tried to create a File array, and created a variable with a value of 4096L. I attempted to say "if(file.length <= 4096L) { show the Dialog window}, but now every single directory is showing it. Every folder contains the ".", and ".." metadata files, which is messing things up. I even tried "if.flie.toString().contains(".") && file.toString().contains(".."), however, EVERY folder contains this, which won't work. I'm rather lost at this point because I don't know how to tell the program to find a directory that ONLY contains that metadata.

Comment: You can loop through your file list and check if there is any files that aren't metadata

Comment: You can specifically check for that?! I must know how!

Comment: Does it have something to do with substrings and the "." ".." files?

Comment: Why can't you just check names? If that isn't possible, why can't you use isHidden() or length()